# Resolving with Ninject in filters MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, dependency-injection, filter, ninject

Hey, I have been searching all over for a solution to injecting into action filters.  I have found a few solutions but they were implemented with an older version of ninject/mvc.  Has anyone found a simple solution to this problem? I have been blocked for a day trying to get a clean implementation.

I have looked at [this solution](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/02/10/how-to-use-ninject-to-inject-dependencies-into-asp.net-mvc.aspx) but a lot of the functions he uses are deprecated in Ninject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ninjet.Web.Mvc has support for this and the source code comes with a sample application that has filter injection. See https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc. The only thing that you have to do is adding a porperty with the Inject attribute to your action filter.

MVC3 has even better support see http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/11/13/official-ninject-mvc-extension-gets-support-for-mvc3/#more-2004

Comment: I used the InjectAttribute in one of my filters which worked but I had an issue when I created a subclass of the AuthorizeAttribute.  When I would do my authorization validation Ninject had not yet initialized the interface.  I have updated to MVC3 and have updated my Ninject.Web.MVC dll.  The examples with the constructor injection is just what I wanted.

Comment: Any other problems or can this be considered as closed? Btw, it would be nice to accept if you'd start to accept answers to give a feedback.